# How can I toggle between two functions in Elisp?

Tags: minor-mode, commands

I would like to use the `F9` key to toggle between the `modus-themes-select` and `ef-themes-select` functions. When I call the `ef-themes-select`, a minibuffer pops up to select an Ef theme:

[image]

Now when I press the F9 one more time I want to switch to the `modus-themes-select` instead, and when I press the F9 again then switch back to the `ef-themes-select` and so on. I want to toggle between the two functions by pressing F9:

[image]

I would be grateful if someone could help me write a custom function for that. Thank you.

Comment: Potentially (perhaps depending on what those commands you've mentioned actually do) your custom command could act based on `last-command`.  Refer to `C-h i g (elisp)Command Loop Info`.  Note that it's typical to `(setq this-command ...)` when a command is pretending to be a different command -- so if you have a custom command which simply calls either A or B interactively, it can set that so that everything else also thinks that's the command which was called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two simple ways to do what you request (using predefined commands `end|beginning-of-line`, so you can see it easily).

**Old school** (essentially what you came up with):

```lisp
(defvar bol/eol 'end-of-line "Current bol/eol command.")

(defun bol/eol ()
  "Alternately invoke `beginning-of-line' and `end-of-line'."
  (interactive)
  (funcall (prog1 (setq bol/eol  (if (eq bol/eol 'end-of-line)
                                     'beginning-of-line
                                   'end-of-line))
             bol/eol)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'bol/eol)
```

**Newer school**:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode bol/eol-mode
  "Alternately invoke `beginning-of-line' and `end-of-line'."
  :global t
  (funcall (if bol/eol-mode 'beginning-of-line 'end-of-line)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'bol/eol-mode)
```

(`define-minor-mode` auto-creates a global variable named the same as the mode command, which holds the current state.)

Answer (score 1):

My unskilled snippet, would work anyway..

```lisp
(setq-default my-themes-select-flag nil) ;; this is a global flag to have only `t` or `'nil`.

(defun my-themes-select ()
  "Calls modus-themes-select and ef-themes-select alternately."
  (interactive)
  (if my-themes-select-flag
      (modus-themes-select) ;; when the flag is t.
    (ef-themes-select)) ;; when the flag is nil.
  (setq my-themes-select-flag (not my-themes-select-flag))) ;; invert the flag after every call.

(define-key global-map (kbd "<f9>") 'my-themes-select)
```